# Laravel 4 Datatables Server Side Processing

Tags: php, laravel, server-side, datatables-1.10, laravel-4.2

Hello Stackoverflow i am doing a webbased project right now that displaying all the products of my office now i am encountering problem now i have this page and i used datatables server side processing

Here the view:

```
<table id="dloadTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
       <tr>
       <th>File ID Number</th>
       <th>File Name</th>
       <th>File Type</th>
       <th>Date Issued</th>
       <th>Uploader</th>

       <th>Action</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        <th>File ID Number</th>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>File Type</th>
        <th>Date Issued</th>
        <th>Uploader</th>

        <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
     </tfoot>
   </table>
```

Controller:

```
public function getAdvanceFilterData()
    {

        $files = Files::select(array('files.id','files.file_name','files.file_type','files.date','files.username'));

        return Datatables::of($files)->make(true);
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/getfilesdata', 'FileController@dloadFile');
```

And js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#dloadTable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/getfilesdata',
            dataSrc:""
        },
        order: [[1,'desc']],
        columnDefs: [ { //this prevents errors if the data is null
            targets: "_all",
            defaultContent: ""
            } ],
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'files.id'},
            {data: 'file_name', name: 'files.file_name'},
            {data: 'file_type', name: 'files.file_type'},     
            {data: 'date', name: 'files.date'},
            {data: 'username', name: 'files.username'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}

        ]
    });

} );
```

And when i try to check what i get in my controller its not the data i expect its not returning JSON Data what should i do?. TIA

Comment: Is `files` a table in your database?

Comment: Yes Peter that was the name one of the table in my database

Comment: Have you checked that you get the appropriate data in `$files` ?

Comment: @PeterDarmis yes i checked it already but unfortunately its not in JSON format you can check it here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwBLqPiSk-9OXZEazU2Y09ieHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: is this what is returned server-side in `$files`? It is ok. Can you check the output of `var_dump(Datatables::of($files)->make(true));`

Answer (score 0):

> You need two routes for it to work. First route is for displaying the
>   table view and the 2nd route is for processing dataTables json
>   response. On your example, `getAdvanceFilterData` is only for
>   processing the json response. You need to add additional route like
>   `getIndex` does in this [example](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter) and load the appropriate view.

An example of your controller class

```
class FilesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Displays datatables front end view
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('files.index');
    }

    /**
     * Process datatables ajax request.
     */
    public function getAdvanceFilterData()
    {
        $files = DB::table('files')->select(array('files.id','files.file_name','files.file_type','files.date','files.username'));

        return Datatables::of($files)->make(true);
    }
}
```

Routing

```
Route::controller('files', 'FilesController', [
    'anyData'  => 'files.data',
    'getIndex' => 'files',
]);
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('files.data') !!}',
    order: [[1,'desc']],
    columnDefs: [{//this prevents errors if the data is null
        targets: "_all",
        defaultContent: ""
        }],
    columns: [{data: 'id', name: 'files.id'},
              {data: 'file_name', name: 'files.file_name'},
              {data: 'file_type', name: 'files.file_type'},     
              {data: 'date', name: 'files.date'},
              {data: 'username', name: 'files.username'},
              {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable:false}]
    });
});
```

Comment: I have this 1st route that you have just said but i think its not working to my project i am trying to use this sample https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package                        public function getAdvanceFilter()
    {
        return view('datatables.eloquent.advance-filter');
    }